# Is there a faster method to do a Pandas groupby cumulative mean?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a lookup reference table in Python that calculates the `cumulative mean` of a Player's previous (by `datetime`) games scores, grouped by venue. However, for my specific need, a player should have previously played a minimum of 2 times at the relevant Venue for a `'Venue Preference'` `cumulative mean` calculation.

`df` format looks like the following:

| DateTime | Player | Venue | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-25 17:15:00 | Tim | Stadium A | 20 |
| 2021-09-27 10:00:00 | Blake | Stadium B | 30 |

My existing code that works perfectly, but unfortunately is very slow, is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

VenueSum = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['DateTime', 'Player', 'Venue'])['Score'].sum().reset_index(name = 'Sum'))
VenueSum['Cumulative Sum'] = VenueSum.sort_values('DateTime').groupby(['Player', 'Venue'])['Sum'].cumsum()
VenueCount = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['DateTime', 'Player', 'Venue'])['Score'].count().reset_index(name = 'Count'))
VenueCount['Cumulative Count'] = VenueCount.sort_values('DateTime').groupby(['Player', 'Venue'])['Count'].cumsum()
VenueLookup = VenueSum.merge(VenueCount, how = 'outer', on = ['DateTime', 'Player', 'Venue'])
VenueLookup['Venue Preference'] = np.where(VenueLookup['Cumulative Count'] >= 2, VenueLookup['Cumulative Sum'] / VenueLookup['Cumulative Count'], np.nan)
VenueLookup = VenueLookup.drop(['Sum', 'Cumulative Sum', 'Count', 'Cumulative Count'], axis = 1)
```

I am sure there is a way to calculate the `cumulative mean` in one step without first calculating the `cumulative sum` and `cumulative count`, but unfortunately I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Eyeballing your code, you seem to be doing the first group-then-sort operation twice; you could extract that to a local to save doing some duplicate work...

Comment: You can compute cumulative mean using: `...expanding().mean()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC remove 2 groupby by aggregate by `sum` and `size` first and then cumulative sum by both columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['DateTime', 'Player', 'Venue'])['Score'].agg(['sum','count'])
df1 = df1.groupby(['Player', 'Venue'])[['sum', 'count']].cumsum().reset_index()
df1['Venue Preference'] = np.where(df1['count'] >= 2, df1['sum'] / df1['count'], np.nan)
df1 = df1.drop(['sum', 'count'], axis=1)
print (df1)
              DateTime Player      Venue  Venue Preference
0  2021-09-25 17:15:00    Tim  Stadium A               NaN
1  2021-09-27 10:00:00  Blake  Stadium B               NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the new code works perfect and is ~2.82x faster!

Comment: @Fonti - one thing, is necessary `df1.sort_values('DateTime')` ? Maybe it should be removed.

Comment: and use only `df1 = df1.groupby(['Player', 'Venue'])[['sum', 'count']].cumsum().reset_index()`

Comment: I have already previously sorted, yes, so I will remove. Thank you again @jezrael